# Is there "alias url" for stackexchange inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox, hyperlinks

I would like to redirect to stackexchange inbox from my mobile app. To be exact - I want to get [to this information](https://stackexchange.com/users/179196/jumbo?tab=inbox) for user.  But I don't know nor the user's name or his id.

But I would expect that the site can redirect user based on cookies. So I would like to use url similar to this: `https://stackexchange.com/inbox`.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

(I am not sure if SO is the right site to ask this Q.)

Comment: Are you using the Stack Exchange API? If so, then the appropriate site would be [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)

Comment: Tricky question :) I am using SE API, but in this particular case I would like to avoid it a try to find some straightforward and easy to use solution - ideally some static URL. (I can imagine this can be done through API.)